# Service 'connect' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c cd /kafka/libs && curl -sO https://jdbc... returned a non-zero code: 6

Tags: postgresql, elasticsearch, debezium

I tried docker-compose up this yml file https://github.com/YegorZaremba/sync-postgresql-with-elasticsearch-example/blob/master/docker-compose.yaml

there is no error in my docker desktop but in my centos machine i get this error

> Service 'connect' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c cd /kafka/libs && curl -sO [https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download/postgresql-$POSTGRES_VERSION.jar'](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download/postgresql-$POSTGRES_VERSION.jar%27) returned a non-zero code: 6

in below line of this file

https://github.com/YegorZaremba/sync-postgresql-with-elasticsearch-example/blob/master/debezium-jdbc-es/Dockerfile

```
# Deploy PostgreSQL JDBC Driver
RUN cd /kafka/libs && curl -sO  
https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download/postgresql-$POSTGRES_VERSION.jar
```